# How are ditzy characters classified?

Tags: tropes, terminology, lucky-star

How are ditzy/airhead characters classified in anime/manga? For example, while Lucky Star's Kagami is a *tsundere*, her airhead sister, Tsukasa, is a ***_*__*_*____**?

Comment: Her sister's name is Tsukasa. 
I've seen characters like that tagged as 'Ditzy' on some sites but I don't know if that's an actual thing...

Comment: @MrPineapple Thanks. I'm actually looking for a Japanese classification along the lines of _tsundere_, _yandere_, etc.

Comment: I think Tsukasa's isn't included in the dere classifications because `dere` means `lovestruck` and I think dumb or stupid characters fall into different classification, though I'm not sure to what.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably looking for the term **dojikko** for Tsukasa:

> Dojikko is Japanese for clumsy with the feminine suffix "-ko"
>   added on the end. The attraction is not limited to Japan, the concept
>   of a Cute Clumsy Girl has worldwide appeal, mainly because her
>   clumsiness makes her more approachable. The main difference is that in
>   the West a Cute Clumsy Girl is probably supposed to make the audience
>   chuckle, while Dojikkos tend towards making them say, "Awwww! She's so
>   cute!"

Source: [TVTropes article on dojikko](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dojikko)

Also, Kagami is not really a tsundere, unless you think she is in love with Konata, which some fans really do seem to support. She should probably be classified as the **tsukkomi** (straight man) in **manzai**, where Konata is usually the **boke**:

> Called manzai in Japanese, this is a kind of Straight Man and Wise Guy
>   duo, but it's also the interaction between two characters who
>   constantly play off each other. A boke's job is to set up the gag by
>   telling a story or explaining a fact which is obviously false (making
>   him an idiot) or flawed (making him sneaky). The tsukkomi is, roughly,
>   the Straight Man who has to correct him, often physically.

Source: [TVTropes article on manzai](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BokeAndTsukkomiRoutine)

Edit: Since dojikko didn't seem to be a proper answer, I looked up more character types on Japanese websites and think I found exactly what you're looking for. It actually fits in really well with my explanation of manzai above. My new answer is that Tsukasa is a **tennen boke** (natural boke, also translated as natural airhead):

> A tennen boke is an eccentric person who has exceptional talent in
>   being a natural boke. Even though a person can be called a tennen
>   boke, there is no such term as tennen tsukkomi. In manzai, the boke
>   deliberately entices both the tsukkomi and the audience's laughter by
>   executing a calculated line. However, the tennen boke describes
>   someone who naturally (without any preparation or purpose) says
>   boke-like things.
>
> It can also be called simply "tennen" or "tennen kyara" (tennen
>   character).

Source: Translated from the [Japanese Wikipedia article on tennen boke](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E7%84%B6%E3%83%9C%E3%82%B1)

So basically, a boke is someone who says dumb things on purpose in order to anger the tsukkomi and make other people laugh. However, a tennen boke says the same dumb things without realizing they are actually dumb.

Comment: Thank you. Although clumsy != ditzy, _dojikko_ is close.

Comment: @coleopterist I've added information about another character type that may be what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you :) This is interesting too. But it seems that _tennen boke_ is part of a _manzai_ act rather than something standalone. (BTW, Google Translate offer _henjin_ as a translation of _airhead_ which seems, well, _hen_.)

Comment: @coleopterist You've misunderstood. Tennen boke is not part of any sort of act - it is someone's natural personality.

Comment: is it possible kagami is a tsundere even if not gay for konata? say a platonic tsundere. tsundere is not necessarily romantic right?

Answer (score 2):

I think Tsukasa Hiiragi falls under [The Ditz](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDitz) character classification since she's not too fool to be [The Fool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheFool).

> The Ditz is a character whose defining characteristic is profound
>   stupidity. Female ditzes tend to be sweet and naive, while male ditzes
>   tend to be oafish but lovable. The Ditz is written to appear
>   unintentionally funny. In drama series, he or she provides comic
>   relief.

I think Tsukasa's character doesn't fall into any of the [deredere classifications](http://www.bishoujoproject.com/classifying-heroine-types-dere-dere-tsundere-yandere-kudere/) because first of all, `deredere` means `lovestruck` and she doesn't have any love interest in the anime.